# How to add a directive to Angular app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular – I created a directive called “uploaddirective”

The directive JS file  is in a separate folder from the controller JS file.

The folder paths are:

Scripts\directives\ uploaddirective.js
Scripts\Views\Video_Upload.j

I tried to add the directive to my application as:

```
(function() {
  var testApp;

  testApp = window.angular.module("testApp", ['ngRoute', 'directives/uploaddirective']);

  testApp.controller("videosUploadAppController", function($scope, $http, $compile) {
```

I keep getting this error on my web page:

```
Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error
```

My page head contains:

```
<script src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src ="/Scripts/Views/Video_Upload.js"></script>
```

Here is the script:

```
'use strict';

var uploaddirective = angular.module('uploaddirective', []);

uploaddirective.directive('file', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            file: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            el.bind('change', function (event) {
                var files = event.target.files;
                var file = files[0];
                scope.file = file;
                scope.$parent.file = file;
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I am using angular: v1.2.26

Can you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You app definition should have module ’uploaddirective’

```
 testApp = window.angular.module("testApp",  
[
   'ngRoute', 
   'uploaddirective'
]);
```

Comment: @user1526912 does it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you included "\directives\uploaddirective.js" in your main source file? This is how your other scripts will get access to it. Looks like you also need:

   ```
   <script src ="/Scripts/directives/uploaddirective.js"></script>
   ```
2. And also can you post the code of your directive